# Field "district" doesn't have a default value

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error "Field "district" doesn't have a default value" every time I try to execute the insert into command on my VB project.

I don't even have the field on my database anymore. I have already deleted it on my database.

Need advise on what to do.

Thanks.

```
 Try

            Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO main (penro,area,year) values ('" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + ComboBox6.SelectedItem + "')", connection)
        Dim myDatatable As New DataTable
        myAdapter.Fill(myDatatable)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may specify the column `district` as a `Not Null` at the time of construction of the table.their for you cannot insert a value without giving a value to that field or else you need to specify a default value for this field

you can alter the table structure with the following code

```
ALTER TABLE `main`  MODIFY COLUMN `district` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Available'
```

Comment: thanks! it's working now. I created a new database just to be sure.